# Clustered standard errors in R

Tags: standard-error, fixed-effects-model

I have data on US states across 10 years connected with accidents. Traffic fertility is my dependent variable, independent variables are: age, alcohol consumption, rainfall, number of miles travelled and income. My panel is macro and I have to use clustered standard errors but I dont know how I should cluster my data- by time, by state or both by state and by time?

Comment: Could you explain how it is possible that you "have to use clustered SEs" and yet not know what the clustering variables ought to be?  How did you determine to use clustered SEs in the first place?

Comment: Because I have serial correlation in my data and heteroskedasticity and I found information that in this situation I should use clustered SEs.